# If AttributeSet is an interface, how does it store/retrieve values from xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, attributes

If AttributeSet is an interface, then where does the external (concrete) reading/storing of values from xml lie? i.e. what is the concrete class that has storing/retrieve values delegated to it by AttributeSet? i'm on a goose hunt shmoozing through source code, but i still can't find where the magic is happening. thanks for the help, guys!

Comment: Short answer: in the non-public area of the SDK. For example, [`android.util.XmlPullAttributes`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/util/XmlPullAttributes.java#XmlPullAttributes) and [`android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/res/XmlBlock.java#XmlBlock.Parser) are both concrete implementations of `AttributeSet`. You may find the sources on GitHub or GrepCode useful for browsing this kind of stuff.

Comment: grepCode site is down for whatever reason, and yeah i comb a lot through Resources.Theme to find the implementation, but i'll look again, and at the other classes you've mentioned thanks bro!

Comment: could you do me a favor and provide the links to GitHub, you're links are to grepcode, but the server is down :(

Comment: Have you tried the links in my previous comment? They go off to GrepCode and work just fine for me. Github equivalents (just Google them next time...): [`XmlPullAttributes`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/util/XmlPullAttributes.java) and [`XmlBlock$Parser`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/content/res/XmlBlock.java#77)

Comment: yeah i tried them, for whatever reason, on my system, it says GrepCode's servers are down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skipping some details in the middle here, but the `AttributeSet` you're using is typically an `XmlResourceParser` obtained from `AssetManager`, which is the class responsible for managing Android application resources including AAPT-compiled XML. The asset manager creates an `XmlBlock.Parser` for parsing a specific resource block, which represents an XML file, using `XmlBlock.newParser()`.

`XmlBlock.Parser` implements `XmlResourceParser` and calls through to native code for parsing AAPT-compiled XML.

`XmlResourceParser` extends both `XmlPullParser` and `AttributeSet`.

Comment: thanks a lot for this. it gives me a better understanding of where all the puzzle pieces are at. Now the issue is knowing what those pieces truly look like. do you know any credible resources that explain Xml parsing in depth?

Comment: As far as I know, we don't have any first-party documentation on how AAPT or the low-level Android resource system works. You would need to look at the source code. Or, you might be able to convince Jonathan Levin to cover it in the next edition of [Android Internals: A Confectioner's Cookbook](http://newandroidbook.com/) which does (unofficially) document a lot of low-level details of the Android OS.